# How to get full Google Analytics reporting features for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have set up Firebase and Google Analytics for my mobile app. However, I noticed that the reporting functions in GA is much limited (comparing to the demo project). For example, I cannot customize my dashboard. Streamview is also very limited.

What I need to do to get the full GA functions for my firebase app?

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics and Google Analytics for Firebase are different platforms from one another. If you haven't already, you can [link Firebase to Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en). This will give you access to use some of the advanced features of Google Analytics. See this [Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-google-analytics-upgrade.html) and [Firebase Analytics FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#analytics) page for your reference.

Comment: Yes I have done the upgrade. That is still a limited set of functions. Things like the realtime streamview are very limited. Is there to way to get the full GA functionalities with firebase?

Comment: You can file a feature request for missing functionalities or reports that you would like Firebase to have.